# Attempting to create a user on macOS via ansible

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible playbook which works fine on Linux, but fails on macOS with a strange error.

```
- name: Create the watcher user member of the watchers group
  user:
    comment: "Read-only user for folks to inspect builds"
    name: "{{ watch_user }}"
    group: watchers
    state: present
    shell: /bin/bash
    createhome: yes
    home: "{{ watch_user_home }}"
  become: yes
  when: watch_user_enabled
```

When this runs on a Mac, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ansible_jfT4nc/ansible_module_user.py", line 2278, in <module>
    main()
  File "/tmp/ansible_jfT4nc/ansible_module_user.py", line 2235, in main
    info = user.user_info()
  File "/tmp/ansible_jfT4nc/ansible_module_user.py", line 618, in user_info
    info = self.get_pwd_info()
  File "/tmp/ansible_jfT4nc/ansible_module_user.py", line 613, in get_pwd_info
    return list(pwd.getpwnam(self.name))
KeyError: 'getpwnam(): name not found: watcher'
```

So, two part question:

1. How can I access `/tmp/ansible_jfT4nc/ansible_module_user.py`? I
   tried `keep_remote_files` and it doesn't seem to work
2. Why is it failing anyways?

Comment: There seems to be an issue with the module when a half baked user gets created. You should try running `sudo dscl . -delete /Users/watcher` to delete the existing user and then try again

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below are the commands you run when creating a user on Mac

```
sudo dscl . -create /Users/username
sudo dscl . -create /Users/username UserShell /bin/bash
sudo dscl . -create /Users/username RealName "John Smith"
sudo dscl . -create /Users/username UniqueID 1001
sudo dscl . -create /Users/username PrimaryGroupID 1000
sudo dscl . -create /Users/username NFSHomeDirectory /Local/Users/username
sudo dscl . -passwd /Users/username password
sudo dscl . -append /Groups/admin GroupMembership username
```

As soon as the first command is executed the `user` actually exists on the system. Now when ansible runs and fails to run the post-create steps of the user because of some reason, the next time operation may fail. One way to reproduce the same is to set the user directory to some non-existent parent folder, let the first run fail, update the yaml and run again

```
- name: Do this
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Create the group
    group:
      name: watchers
      state: present
  - name: Create the watcher user member of the watchers group
    user:
      comment: "Read-only user for folks to inspect builds"
      name: watcher
      group: watchers
      #password: test
      state: present
      shell: /bin/bash
      createhome: yes
      home: "/home/watcher"
```

Running the playbook first time will generate below error

```
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ansible_rLmVcE/ansible_module_user.py", line 2255, in <module>
    main()
  File "/tmp/ansible_rLmVcE/ansible_module_user.py", line 2185, in main
    (rc, out, err) = user.create_user()
  File "/tmp/ansible_rLmVcE/ansible_module_user.py", line 1740, in create_user
    os.makedirs(self.home)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 45] Operation not supported: '/home/watcher'

fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_rLmVcE/ansible_module_user.py\", line 2255, in <module>\n    main()\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_rLmVcE/ansible_module_user.py\", line 2185, in main\n    (rc, out, err) = user.create_user()\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_rLmVcE/ansible_module_user.py\", line 1740, in create_user\n    os.makedirs(self.home)\n  File \"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py\", line 157, in makedirs\n    mkdir(name, mode)\nOSError: [Errno 45] Operation not supported: '/home/watcher'\n",
    "module_stdout": "",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE",
    "rc": 1
}
```

Now after correct the folder mistake, if you re-run the playbook the error will change to

```
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ansible_18GFi3/ansible_module_user.py", line 2255, in <module>
    main()
  File "/tmp/ansible_18GFi3/ansible_module_user.py", line 2211, in main
    info = user.user_info()
  File "/tmp/ansible_18GFi3/ansible_module_user.py", line 597, in user_info
    info = self.get_pwd_info()
  File "/tmp/ansible_18GFi3/ansible_module_user.py", line 592, in get_pwd_info
    return list(pwd.getpwnam(self.name))
KeyError: 'getpwnam(): name not found: watcher'

fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_18GFi3/ansible_module_user.py\", line 2255, in <module>\n    main()\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_18GFi3/ansible_module_user.py\", line 2211, in main\n    info = user.user_info()\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_18GFi3/ansible_module_user.py\", line 597, in user_info\n    info = self.get_pwd_info()\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_18GFi3/ansible_module_user.py\", line 592, in get_pwd_info\n    return list(pwd.getpwnam(self.name))\nKeyError: 'getpwnam(): name not found: watcher'\n",
    "module_stdout": "",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE",
    "rc": 1
}
```

This is because of some assumptions that the module is making, so it is a bug in the user module for mac.

Now lets delete our user using

```
dscl . -delete /Users/watcher
```

And try the playbook again, and now you will get the correct output

```
changed: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "changed": true,
    "comment": "Read-only user for folks to inspect builds",
    "create_home": true,
    "group": 501,
    "home": "/Users/watcher",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "append": false,
            "comment": "Read-only user for folks to inspect builds",
            "create_home": true,
            "createhome": true,
            "expires": null,
            "force": false,
            "generate_ssh_key": null,
            "group": "watchers",
            "groups": null,
            "home": "/Users/watcher",
            "local": null,
            "login_class": null,
            "move_home": false,
            "name": "watcher",
            "non_unique": false,
            "password": null,
            "remove": false,
            "seuser": null,
            "shell": "/bin/bash",
            "skeleton": null,
            "ssh_key_bits": 0,
            "ssh_key_comment": "ansible-generated on TarunLalwani-2.local",
            "ssh_key_file": null,
            "ssh_key_passphrase": null,
            "ssh_key_type": "rsa",
            "state": "present",
            "system": false,
            "uid": null,
            "update_password": "always"
        }
    },
    "name": "watcher",
    "shell": "/bin/bash",
    "state": "present",
    "system": false,
    "uid": 615130252
}
```

You can probably open this as a issue on their github repo.

Comment: Wow, indeed. Deleting the user then re-running the playbook works.

So basically the fact that I got it wrong initially at some point hosed it for all future runs?

Comment: I guess I need to wrap this into a block with a rescue task to delete the user if adding it failed, as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35892455/ansible-execute-task-or-handler-if-any-task-failed

Comment: Bonus awarded... would be nice if there was a way to retry after a rescue, but that will be a different matter.