# Ansible - send notification on success and failed tasks

Tags: ansible

I've been reading and testing the block module for error handling and with the help of the following question [Ansible: execute task (or handler) if any task failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35892455/ansible-execute-task-or-handler-if-any-task-failed) really helped to understand the case.
Now, what I'd like to accomplish is to get notified on **success** tasks.
So eventually, I'll be notified on both success and failed tasks.
How can it be accomplish without placing each task in dedicated block module, also, I've thought of using *include_tasks* and looping over the tasks but I'm not sure this is correct and also the tasks must be executed in specific order.

So how do I write it correctly in a way that each task will have both rescue task and also notify on success?
Also, how do I pass the task name and it's output as a message to the handler?

**pseudo code for handling the failed tasks:**

```
--- # Event Handling
- hosts:         localhost  
  connection:    local
  gather_facts:  no

  tasks:
    - name: Installing packages
      block:
        - command1
        - command2
        - command3
          notify: Success Handler
      rescue:
        - name: Sending alerts
          notify: Failed task

 handlers: 
   - name: Success Handler
     debug: 
       msg: "task {{ task_id$ }} was success"
   - name: Failed task
     debug:
       msg: "task {{ task_id$ }} failed, the error was {{ task_id: failed results }}""
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share some test code?

Comment: yes, I've included it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You almost gave the solution. Why not creating a import playbook or even a role and pass the command sequentially with `{{with_items}}`?

Like:

```
  - name: Run My Tasks Role
    include_role:
      name: tasksandnotification
    vars:
      taskvalue: "{{ item }}"
    with_items:
      - task1
      - task2
```

And then in the role/tasks/main.yml

```
- name: Installing packages
      block:
        - "{{ taskvalue }}"
          notify: Success Handler
      rescue:
        - name: Sending alerts
          notify: Failed task
```

and role/handlers/main.yml

```
   - name: Success Handler
     debug: 
       msg: "task {{ taskvalue }} was success"
   - name: Failed task
     debug:
       msg: "task {{ taskvalue }} failed, the error was {{ taskvalue: failed results }}"
```

I haven't fully tested but is the idea I have in my mind.