# How to run a task if any of the roles failed?

Tags: ansible

We are having our validation tasks defined in roles.

```
- name: validation Operations
  hosts: all
  become: yes
  gather_facts: yes
  serial: 1
  roles:
    - StorageArray_setup_cleanup
    - StorageArray_restapi
    - StorageArray_operations
    - StorageArray_operations_negative
```

There is a fact named "testreport" is present in these roles. (testreport is a logfile name.) If any of the roles are failed , i need to display the testreport contents via a task so that user can know till failure how many validations are passed .

In case of blocks, error handling is there such as rescue and always. But when it comes to roles ,i am not finding any. (There is a question already there but which will work if task is failed. In my case based on role failure i need to execute a task)

How to run a task if roles failed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ansible: execute task (or handler) if any task failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35892455/ansible-execute-task-or-handler-if-any-task-failed)

Comment: @LinSel That post will work if a task is failed. Using blocks i can resolve that. But in my playbook only roles are there. So that solution will not work

Comment: i think @LinSel is right : your roles are made of tasks, so if a task in your roles fails, your current role fails, and it will trigger the `rescue:` in your playbook

Comment: @Samselvaprabu (and tassinp): The link is neither about tasks/roles  nor block/rescue. The accepted solution is [slack](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/slack.py)  which sends status updates (about tasks, roles, block, rescue, ...)  to a Slack channel.